# How do I allow outgoing connections via iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, redhat, connection

I have two servers. The program on the first needs to communicate with the second on port 2194.

I know its not working, because when I do:

```
root@server1 [~]# telnet myserver2.com 2194
Trying 123.123.123.98...
telnet: connect to address 123.123.123.98: Connection timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

---

```
server1# iptables -L -n

Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
...
...

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
...

Chain LOCALINPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
...

Chain LOCALOUTPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
...

Chain LOGDROPIN (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain LOGDROPOUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: but it works when you do telnet localhost 2194 on server1 ? what about telnet server1spublicip 2194 from server1 ?

Comment: telnet localhost 2194 on server2 works. telnet server2ipaddress 2194 on server2 works as well.

Comment: con you do : iptables -L -n on both servers, and tell me if you get more than the following (i dont want to see your rules etc ;-)) Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: Hello! See the edit please...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To allow outgoing connections from server1 to server2 on TCP port 2194, use this on server1:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <server2ip> --dport 2194 -j ACCEPT
```

To allow incoming connections from server1 to server2 on TCP port 2194, use this on server2:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s <server1ip> --dport 2194 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Crap - I did the first, didnt work. I did the second, that didnt work either... I may have very restrictive  settings in place... see the edit earlier

Comment: Try using "-I" instead of "-A"; this puts the new rules *above* all other ones that may already be in place.

Comment: Should I be doing anything different if the application actually uses the domain name, rather than the ip address directly?

Comment: Woah... am able to telnet from the prompt just by doing the first statement...

Comment: Its minus-I as in "i" for folks who might read that as an L

Answer (score 7):

Just a few pointers

Is the service you are running listening only on localhost? Run

```
netstat -ltn
```

If you see a line like `0.0.0.0:2194` then you are ok. If you see `127.0.0.1:2194` then you are listening only on local connections (or `:::2194` and `::1:2194` respectively for IPv6 addresses, shown as `tcp6` lines).

What are the current iptables rules?

```
iptables -L
```

Is the policy DROP/REJECT (if it isn't it should be, for all chains)? Is there a specific rule for the port you need?

If it is a firewall issue, then a either modifying the offending rule or adding a rule like

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2194 -j ACCEPT
```

should do the trick (untested)

=== EDIT ===

To test network issue a good tool is `tcpdump`. Run it on both servers while trying to connect and see where the packets are going. e.g. on server 1 run:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n host server2.com
```

and on server 2 run:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n host server1.com
```

Then try to connect. You should see all TCP packets dumped on the screen, from the source and destination. With this info you should be  able to pinpoint where is the issue.

Comment: Hi Dan - I dont think server2 has any problem accepting the connection (I'm able to connect to it using my home pc), but I think server1 doesnt allow the outgoing connection...

Comment: iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2194 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Hi c10k, that didnt work... And tryign to telnet didnt work either

Comment: Added a few other ideas

Comment: Hi here 2194 is my port number or target IP port number?

Comment: I want to add  targetIP with 443 port number